# How to execute this query without imploding my array?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Can I execute a query like this? If not, can you give me a better way to do it without walking through my array or imploding  it.

```
    ....
    DECLARE
     examples example[];
     myinput myinput[];
    BEGIN
     select array(select e from mytable e where row_id in (myinput)) into examples
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  e
FROM    mytable e
WHERE   row_id = ANY(myinput)
```